# How to use the len() in an if statement

Tags: python-3.x

I am defining a function, standard_deviation that consumes a list of numbers and returns a float representing their standard deviation. I need to use the len function to return None if the list has fewer than 2 elements.

This is what I have written:

```
SURVEY_RESULTS = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]
def standard_deviation():
    if len(SURVEY_RESULTS) < 2:
        return None
    elif len(SURVEY_RESULTS) > 2:
        stdev = (((sum(square(SURVEY_RESULTS))) - (summate * summate)/(count))/(count - 1)) ** .5
        rounded_stdev = (round(stdev, 2))
    print(rounded_stdev)
```

Nothing prints when I run the code. I have run the code for standard deviation separately so I know that works fine and that my issue lies in my if statement.

Comment: The whole `elif ...` is unnecessary, `else:` would be just fine

Answer (score 0):

There is an alert: you're not considering the case where the `len()` is 2.

The actual answer is here. Did you run after `standard_deviation()` after all the def block? It needs NOT to be indented. With the def, you just defined a function, you didn't run it

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with your environment, because the code is fine. To run it, I removed all the undefined parts from the `stddev =` line, and then called the `standard_deviation()` function. It works as expected:

```
SURVEY_RESULTS = [0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 2]
def standard_deviation():
    if len(SURVEY_RESULTS) < 2:
        return None
    elif len(SURVEY_RESULTS) > 2:
        stdev = sum(SURVEY_RESULTS) ** .5
        rounded_stdev = (round(stdev, 2))
    print(rounded_stdev)

standard_deviation()
```

Output:

```
3.61
```

Try to reduce your code to a minimum example - not only will that produce a better question more likely to attract quality answers, but in doing so you'll probably discover the error lies somewhere else.

Comment: I forgot to mention that the code only does not work when the length of the list is less than 2. I'm trying to test that the code will return None when SURVEY_RESULTS has less than 2 elements.

Comment: That's a different question. Show us how this is *not* working for you now.